# Horizontal braces with XeTeX take too much space

Tags: xetex, braces, boxes, plain-tex

After some experiments and tests, I managed to create the following code for `\upbracefill` and `\downbracefill` in Plain XeTeX, which it seems is that used for `\underbrace` and `\overbrace`:

```
\def\midshift#1{
\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\dimen0=\ht0\advance\dimen0by+\dp0\advance\dimen0by-1ex
\lower.5\dimen0\box0 }

\def\rotatebrace#1{%
\leavevmode\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\rlap{%
\kern.5\wd0\dimen0=\ht0\advance\dimen0by-\dp0%\advance\dimen0by+1ex%
\raise.5\dimen0\hbox{\special{x:gsave}\special{x:rotate 90}}}%
\box0\special{x:grestore}}

[...]

\XeTeXmathchardef\bracelu = 0 3 `\⎧
\XeTeXmathchardef\bracemu = 0 3 `\⎨
\XeTeXmathchardef\braceru = 0 3 `\⎩
\XeTeXmathchardef\bracebar = 0 3 `\⎪
\XeTeXmathchardef\braceld = 0 3 `\⎫
\XeTeXmathchardef\bracemd = 0 3 `\⎬
\XeTeXmathchardef\bracerd = 0 3 `\⎭

\def\upbracefill{\rotatebrace{\midshift{$\bracelu$}}%
    \cleaders\hbox{\rotatebrace{\midshift{$\bracebar$}}}\hfill
    \rotatebrace{\midshift{$\bracemu$}}%
    \cleaders\hbox{\rotatebrace{\midshift{$\bracebar$}}}\hfill
    \rotatebrace{\midshift{$\braceru$}}}%
\def\downbracefill{\rotatebrace{\midshift{$\braceld$}}%
    \cleaders\hbox{\rotatebrace{\midshift{$\bracebar$}}}\hfill
    \rotatebrace{\midshift{$\bracemd$}}%
    \cleaders\hbox{\rotatebrace{\midshift{$\bracebar$}}}\hfill
    \rotatebrace{\midshift{$\bracerd$}}}%
```

Where Cambria Math is loaded for the 3. family.
However, the height of these braces are bigger because of the middle part of the brace, and I can't find a way to shrink/limit the height of the box, without which the brace would fall apart.

I originally used the `:vertical` parameter for the font, which I figured has no dimension in horizontal text.

So how can I make this horizontal brace height smaller? (preferably to the character width, which is now the height.)

Comment: I'm really going to have to remember this for unicode-math...

Comment: Again, not a real answer, but if I were you, I'd save myself the trouble and use LuaTeX instead which already have `\Umathaccent`, `\Umathbotaccent`, `\Umathaccents` and more, check http://www.ntg.nl/maps/38/04.pdf. You can use `luaotfload` package with plain TeX, and most of your code can be reused, but you get better quality OpenType math.

Comment: I understand and accept that as an option, but generally if I meet a problem, I prefer to solve it, if that is possible. (Not very efficient though.)

Comment: @Adam, I do so all the time, but emulating TeX's math engine in macros is no fun.

Comment: @Khaled: On the contrary, I find it can be lots of “fun” `:)`

Comment: @Will: generally speaking, I see no fun in working with TeX macros at all `;)`

Comment: @Khaled: we must agree to disagree then :-)

Comment: I agree with Khaled, and understand Will, and now I feel a little sorry for my comment on Khaled's first comment, because I realized, that it was the proper place to tell such comments. (And it is a useful comment, although I don't stop with that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I saw that `\upbracefill` is used for `\underbrace`, I felt the need to correct this problem, so I take some time to it and look at it to see what choices do I have. Soon I realized that the only good solution is if I shrink the bounding box of each character, with the help of `\setbox`. (The only problem was to do this in the characters right state.) Since the most biggest character is the middle one, I arrange their height to that. (The rest of that characters height is aligned to that, however 0pt height is also ok.)
So here is the result using the above `\rotatebrace` and `\midshift` macros:

```
\def\upbracefill{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\lower.64ex\hbox{\rotatebrace{\midshift{$\bracemu$}}}}\ht0=.1\wd0\dp0=0pt%
    \setbox1=\hbox{\lower.64ex\hbox{\rotatebrace{\midshift{$\bracelu$}}\kern-.2em}}\ht1=.1\wd0\dp1=0pt%
    \setbox2=\hbox{\lower.64ex\hbox{\rotatebrace{\midshift{$\bracebar$}}}}\ht2=.1\wd0\dp2=0pt%
    \setbox3=\hbox{\lower.64ex\hbox{\kern-.2em\rotatebrace{\midshift{$\braceru$}}}}\ht3=.1\wd0\dp3=0pt%
    \box1\cleaders\copy2\hfill\box0\cleaders\box2\hfill\box3}

\def\downbracefill{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\lower.64ex\hbox{\rotatebrace{\midshift{$\bracemd$}}}}\ht0=.1\wd0\dp0=0pt%
    \setbox1=\hbox{\lower.64ex\hbox{\rotatebrace{\midshift{$\braceld$}}\kern-.2em}}\ht1=.1\wd0\dp1=0pt%
    \setbox2=\hbox{\lower.64ex\hbox{\rotatebrace{\midshift{$\bracebar$}}}}\ht2=.1\wd0\dp2=0pt%
    \setbox3=\hbox{\lower.64ex\hbox{\kern-.2em\rotatebrace{\midshift{$\bracerd$}}}}\ht3=.1\wd0\dp3=0pt%
    \box1\cleaders\copy2\hfill\box0\cleaders\box2\hfill\box3}%
```

Here is an example: [image: Horizontal braces example in foreign language text]
The example above uses Calibri for normal text and Cambria for mathematical equations, (just as Office 2007 does) as well as for the braces, as in a Hungarian notes of a class of mine.
**Note:** In some viewer in certain zoom it appears as if it would fallen apart, and the join of the characters seems thicker than they should be. This will be OK in print.

Comment: This means, that I dare to share this beta “package”, as soon as I finish writing the documentation for it ASAP. (With full of spelling errors. :-()

Comment: I'd certainly be happily willing to accept a patch to `unicode-math` if you were interested in taking a look into it.

Comment: I'm interested of such challenges. Now that I take a look at it's site, I'm seriously thinking of offering this pack, and my support.

Comment: I have the feeling, that somehow the ⏟ (U+23DF) and ⏞ (U+23DE) characters should be used, instead of the brace elements (since the font should do this trick, as it works for hat->widehat and tilde->widetilde for Cambria Math), and it may solve a problem; that the braces cannot be smaller a certain size, depending on the element size.

Comment: The hat and tilde solved with combining dialectical marks and \XeTeXmathaccent

Comment: I was thinking using this method for brace fills, but a hbox with a hfill doesn't seem to work.